# Separating environments in GKE: multiple clusters or multiple projects?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

This is my first time using GCP, I have always been an AWS person before this.

As a small team without dedicated DevOps, should we separate our prod and sandbox environments into 2 clusters / VPCs under one GCP project, or should we be going through the hassle of entirely separate GCP projects as well?

What is the industry standard here? If we have IAM setup correctly, what would be the con to having them both in the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to use separate projects for staging and production.

With that, you will get the **isolation**, and clear **separation** between the **staging** & **production** environment. Prevents accidental changes or testing and also prevents downtimes etc.

**Resource management** across the project would be easy for you will have to a better idea bout the resources & management across the project. You properly get a list of resources & billing details in the project.

**Access Management** : Separate projects also have better access control, as only specific users will have prod project across so not everyone hang around the project or view/update the resources.

But the separate project also comes with the challenges of **admin** **work** so you mentioned you are a **small team** without **DevOps** it would be better to go with a **Single project** with **multiple clusters** managed with proper **labels, networks & IAM roles**.

Answer (score 1):

From the **[Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/develop-and-test-pipelines#deployment-environment)** it recommends to use **separate projects** for each environment,This helps to ensure that the production environment is **secure** and that any changes to the sandbox environment don’t affect the production environment. Additionally, having the two environments in separate projects allows for better **resource and cost management**.

If you have strong **IAM controls** in place and are confident that the two environments can be securely separated, then it is possible to keep them in the same project.Set the application name as a folder, it would contain each environment as a separate project resource.You can achieve this by using **[Resource hierarchy](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy)**.Having them in the same project allows for **easier** **sharing** of resources and access control, and makes it easier to monitor, manage, and troubleshoot both environments.